# How many 6-digit numbers can I write?

Tags: combinatorics

I have a statement that says:

> With the numbers $1, 2, 3$ How many of them contain all the digits
>   $1$, $2$ and $3$ at least once?

I must have a number as _ _ _ _ _ _ , with $1, 2, 3$ at least once and with any position, so its possible positions are $6 * 5 * 4 = 120$, also the others 3 digits, can be {$1, 2, 3$} and can repeated so is $3^3 = 27$, and applying multiplicative principle, $120 * 27 = 3240$, but the result is totally wrong, what is wrong in my development ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Total ways to write this: $3^6=729$

Don't include the number '1': $2^6=64$

Thus, the number of ways can be calculated by take away ways that don't include 1,2 or 3, which is $$729-3*64+3=540$$ since 111111, 222222 and 333333 are counted twice.

Comment: According to the answer, must be $540$ instead of $537$

Comment: Sorry--I overcounted 111111,222222 and 333333.

Comment: How you know that numbers are counted twice ?

Comment: I counted 111111 in both the numbers that don't include 2 and the numbers that don't include 3. Similar argument for the other 2.

Answer (score 2):

An example of your error is when you overcount $\color{blue}{321}\color{red}{111}$ and $\color{blue}{32}\color{red}{111}\color{blue}1$ (The blue represents the three numbers you picked first).

Comment: Why ? can you explain me

Comment: In the first example, you pick 3, 2, 1 in the first three positions as seen above. This is one of the $120$ ways to do this. Then you fill in the rest with $1$s. 

In the second, you pick 3, 2, 1 to be in the first, second, and last positions. This is one of the $120$ ways to do that. Then you fill in the rest with $1$s.

But these result in the same thing! You are counting too much then.

Comment: What is $1$s ? , I have not understood, your explanation, you are saying that $321111$ isn't valid ?

Comment: I am saying you have counted this twice. Can you point to a specific sentence you do not understand?